# Does Lazarus support TListBox virtual mode?

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I'm trying to "move" a project to Lazarus from Delphi, but I cannot find the OnData, OnFindData, etc properties of a TListBox in virtual mode. It seems that Lazarus does not support it yet. Is that right?

Comment: Are you sure you mean TListbox and not TListView? If so, then indeed no, but tlistview has them

Comment: (I mean TListBox) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not! Thanks Marco van de Voort for confirming.